# Finding objects in nested arrays in MongoDB Realm

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, realm

Using MongoDB Realm, I want to find a specific field that's nested inside multiple arrays. The document has the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": "05932rkshfkj",
    "email": "user@email.com",
    "library": [
       {
        "isbn": "127395729387",
        "notes": [
            {
                "_noteID": "5tk3hk42jg2kgawef",
                "noteTitle": "title",
            },
            {
                "_noteID": "8hrwefjhwefwaef",
                "noteTitle": "another title",
            }     
         ]    
       }
     ],
    "toRead": []
}
```

I would like to find a note (with a unique `_noteID`) that belongs to a specific book (with a unique `isbn`) located in `library`.

To clarify, the library is an array that holds book objects, and the book itself has an array of note objects.

I'm having trouble writing the query for this operation. I have tried the following query, however this returns all the notes that belong to the book instead of the one I'm looking for based on its `_noteID`:

```
exports = async function(payload, response) {
  
  const {user, bookID, noteID} = payload.query;
  
  let collection = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("myApp").collection("Users"); 
  
    let note = collection.findOne({
    email: user,
    "library.isbn" : `${bookID}`,
    "library.notes" : {$elemMatch: {"_noteID" : noteID}}},  {"library.notes.$": 1}
  )

  return note;
  
}
```

This is what my result shows if I try to query for the second note:

```
    "notes": [
            {
                "_noteID": "5tk3hk42jg2kgawef",
                "noteTitle": "title",
            },
            {
                "_noteID": "8hrwefjhwefwaef",
                "noteTitle": "another title",
            }     
         ]    
       }
```

How can I add a filter so I only receive the note I'm looking for?

What am I missing here? Why doesn't this work? I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: It's a good idea to tag the question with the coding platform so other users with that expertise see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should try this, I am assuming that this solution will help you.**
users.collection.json

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "05932rkshfkj",
    "email" : "user@email.com",
    "library" : [ 
        {
            "isbn" : "127395729387",
            "notes" : [ 
                {
                    "_noteID" : "5tk3hk42jg2kgawef",
                    "noteTitle" : "title"
                }, 
                {
                    "_noteID" : "8hrwefjhwefwaef",
                    "noteTitle" : "another title"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "toRead" : [],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-01T04:12:13.733Z")
}
```

Mongo-aggregation-query.json

```
db.users.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "$and": [{
      "_id": "05932rkshfkj"
    }, {
      "library.isbn": "127395729387"
    }]
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$library"
}, {
  "$unwind": "$library.notes"
}, {
  "$match": {
    "library.notes._noteID": "8hrwefjhwefwaef"
  }
}])
```

result.json

```
/* 1 */

{
    "_id" : "05932rkshfkj",
    "email" : "user@email.com",
    "library" : {
        "isbn" : "127395729387",
        "notes" : {
            "_noteID" : "8hrwefjhwefwaef",
            "noteTitle" : "another title"
        }
    },
    "toRead" : [],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-01T04:12:13.733Z")
}
```

You can also use $filter

Query.json

```
var email = "user@email.com";
var bookID = "127395729387";
var noteID = "8hrwefjhwefwaef";
db.users.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "$and": [{
                "email": email
            }, {
                "library.isbn": bookID
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$library"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "email": 1,
            "library.isbn": 1,
            "library.notes": {
                "$filter": {
                    input: "$library.notes",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$item._noteID", noteID]
                    }
                }
            },
            "toRead": 1,
            "createdAt": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Result.json

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "05932rkshfkj",
    "email" : "user@email.com",
    "library" : {
        "isbn" : "127395729387",
        "notes" : [ 
            {
                "_noteID" : "8hrwefjhwefwaef",
                "noteTitle" : "another title"
            }
        ]
    },
    "toRead" : [],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-01T04:12:13.733Z")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The results were a bit different but I was able to figure it out by combining both of your approaches.